# Relatório e programa diferentes C#/WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu tenho um aplicativo em que tenho que fazer um programa de secagem para uma estufa, onde faz a medição e umidades de uma madeira, programo ele e o envio para a máquina e até ai tudo certo, mas quando vou ver o relatório da tal secagem, as umidades são totalmente diferentes, sabendo que a única diferença nos dois formulários devia ser só o "Status", coisa que ao programar o programa de secagem não tem:

Relatório do programa:

[image: Programa]

Relatório da Secagem:

[image: Secagem]

e o código feito para o relatório da secagem:

```
 private void CarregarProgramaDeSecagem(List<FaseSecagem> listaFases)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listaFases.Count; i++)
                    {
                          dtgProgramaDaSecagem.Rows.Add(listaFases[i].Fase + 1,
                                listaFases[i].InicioFase,
                                listaFases[i].NumeroLeitura,
                                listaFases[i].Faixa,
                                listaFases[i].Via,
                                listaFases[i].Banho,
                                listaFases[i].DeltaT,  
                            listaFases[i].ValorDesejadoSeco.ToString("00.0"),

                              listaFases[i].ValorDesejadoUmido.ToString("00.0"),
                                listaFases[i].UmidadeRelativa.ToString("00.0"),

                               listaFases[i].UmidadeEquilibrio.ToString("00.0"),
                                listaFases[i].Potencial.ToString("0.0"),
                                listaFases[i].VMot,
                                listaFases[i].TempoDaFase,
                                listaFases[i].Status);

                        dtgProgramaDaSecagem.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = i % 2 == 0 ? Color.LightGreen : Color.White;
                    }

                    dtgProgramaDaSecagem.ClearSelection();

                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    LogErro logErro = new LogErro();
                    logErro.DMC = _secagem.IdDispositivo;
                    logErro.Descricao = "Erro ao tentar carregar programa da secagem do relatório da secagem";
                    string dataHora = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    logErro.Data = dataHora.Substring(0, 10);
                    logErro.Hora = dataHora.Substring(11, 8);
                    logErro.MaisDetalhes = error.Message;
                    LogErroDAO.InserirLogErro(logErro);
                }

            }
```

E abaixo o código com os cálculos feitos:

```
 ////Método para o cálculo da umidade relativa
        public static double[] calcularUmidadeRelativa(float bulboSeco, float bulboUmido, float umidadeMedia, int umFinal)
        {
            double pVu, pSs, uRu = 0, k1, k2, w, h, uEu, uE, p, pM;
            double[] resultado = new double[3];

            if (bulboUmido != 0)
            {
                pVu = (9.1466 - (2316 / (273 + bulboUmido)));
                pVu = Math.Exp(pVu * Math.Log(10));
                pVu = pVu - 0.5 * (bulboSeco - bulboUmido);
                pSs = (9.1466 - (2316 / (273 + bulboSeco)));
                pSs = Math.Exp(pSs * Math.Log(10));
                uRu = (pVu / pSs) * 100;
                if (uRu >= 100)
                {
                    uRu = 99.9;
                }
                else if (uRu < 0)
                {
                    uRu = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                uRu = 0;
            }
            k1 = 4.737 + (0.047734 * bulboSeco) - (0.000501228 * bulboSeco * bulboSeco);
            k2 = 0.70594 + (0.00169794 * bulboSeco) - (0.00000555336 * bulboSeco * bulboSeco);
            w = 223.374 + (0.69309 * bulboSeco) + (0.0185328 * bulboSeco * bulboSeco);
            h = (uRu / 100);
            uEu = (((k1 * k2 * h) / (1 + (k1 * k2 * h))) + ((k2 * h) / (1 - (k2 * h)))) * (1800 / w);

            ////Para pegar somente a fração se quiser 3numeros *1000, 2*100, 1*10 etc....            
            //int frac = (int)Math.Truncate((uEu - Math.Truncate(uEu)) * 10);
            //if (frac==5)
            //    uEu = uEu + 0.05;

            uE = uEu;
            if (uE == 0)
            {
                p = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pM = (umFinal / uE);
                p = pM;
            }

            resultado[0] = uRu;
            resultado[1] = uE;
            resultado[2] = p;

            return resultado;
        }
```

UE:

```
public static double[] CalculaUE(float Ps, float UE, int umFinal, double P, int indice, double pU)
    {
        double[] resultado = new double[3];
        double Bu, Uerr1, Uerr2, URAnt, Uru, PVu, PSs, pUE, PUmdRel, K1, K2;
        double w, H, Pm, pUR;


        K1 = 4.737 + (0.047734 * Ps) - (0.000501228 * Ps * Ps);
        K2 = 0.70594 + (0.00169794 * Ps) - (5.55336E-06 * Ps * Ps);
        w = 223.374 + (0.69309 * Ps) + (0.0185328 * Ps * Ps);
        pUE = 100;

        do
        {
            H = (pUE / 100);
            PUmdRel = (((K1 * K2 * H) / (1 + (K1 * K2 * H))) + ((K2 * H) / (1 - (K2 * H)))) * (1800 / w);
            pUE = pUE - 0.1;
        } while (PUmdRel >= UE);

        pUR = H * 100;
        if (pUR >= 100)
        {
            pUR = 99.9;
        }
        if (pUR < 0)
        {
            pUR = 0.0;
        }
        Bu = Ps;
        Uru = 100;

        do
        {
            URAnt = Uru;
            Bu = Bu - 0.1;
            PVu = 9.1466 - (2316 / (273 + Bu));
            PVu = Math.Exp((PVu * Math.Log(10)));
            PVu = PVu - (0.5 * (Ps - Bu));
            PSs = 9.1466 - (2316 / (273 + Ps));
            PSs = Math.Exp((PSs * Math.Log(10)));
            Uru = (PVu / PSs) * 100;
        } while (Uru >= pUR);

        if (Uru < pUR)
        {
            Uerr1 = pUR - Uru;
            Uerr2 = URAnt - pUR;
            if (Uerr1 > Uerr2)
            {
                pU = Bu + 0.1;
            }
            else
            {
                pU = Bu;
            }
        }

        if (pU < 0)
        {
          pU = 0.0;
        }

        if (pUE == 0.0)
        {
            P = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            Pm = umFinal / pUE;
            P = Pm;
        }

        resultado[0] = pU;
        resultado[1] = pUR;
        resultado[2] = P;


        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: tem como postar o codigo do programa? at'e PuC esta correto, nao existe algum extra calculo para as outras colunas?

Comment: @HudsonPH o código é bem extenso, não sei se consigo postar aqui, mas sim, até o Puc está certo, alem dessa aba, há mais indicando os dados da secagem, dados de tratamento e interrupções ocorridas, onde todos estão certos, tirando o programa de secagem que apaerce erros

Comment: Nao da para saber onde estar o erro sem comparar os 2 codigos, pelo menos algum techo do Pot no seu caso 'e o Pt, sim?

Comment: @HudsonPH postei as partes de códigos onde são feitos os cálculos

Comment: qual a necessidade do `do while` o valor vai ser diferente caso a condicacao seja aceita, fora que no primeiro exemplo `bulboUmido` so nao poder ser 0. estao bem diferentes os exemplos.